# Trouble in Making an isPrime Function

Tags: ocaml, primes

This is a homework. OCaml seems to be made by a psychopath.

```
    let prime : int -> bool
= fun n ->
    if n > 2 then 
        let a = n - 1 in
        let rec divisor n a =
            if a > 1 && n mod a = 0 then false
        else if a = 2 && n mod a <> 0 then true
        else divisor n a-1 ;;
    else if n = 2 then true
    else if n = 1 then false
```

I am not good at coding and I know that my `isPrime` algorithm is wrong.
But I wonder where in my code is the mistake that produces the syntax error.

Also is there any way to define the `isPrime` function in a recursive form?

Example:

`let rec prime n = ~`

Comment: Always put white spaces around binary operators: `f n-1` is too prone to misread as `f (n-1)` and hard to find your error.  By writing `f n - 1`, you have more chance to notice it is actually parsed as `(f n) - 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get better responses from experts if you don't gratuitously insult their language :-) But I'm an easygoing guy, so I'll take a stab at your syntax error.

There are quite a few problems in this code. Here are 3 that I see right off:

1. The symbol `;;` is used to tell the interpreter that you've entered a full expression that you want it to evaluate. It's definitely out of place in the middle of a function declaration.
2. Your second `let` doesn't have an associated `in`. Every `let` must have an `in` after it. The only exception is for defining values at the top level of a module (like your `prime` function).
3. The expression `divisor n a-1` is parsed as `(divisor n a) - 1`. You want parentheses like this: `divisor a (n - 1)`.

Comment: Another problem Jeffrey, is that prime, does not cover all cases, particularly n=0. Also prime produce two types unit and int.